# SVN Add file error on commit

Tags: svn, repository, addition

I'm trying to add a file to a subversion repository.  I add the file so that it's under revision, and then I try to commit and get this error.  I know it's not there, I want to add it!  Any help or what transaction 1-1 is would be great.

> Adding         samflag.pl
>
> Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>
> svn: File not found: transaction '1-1', path '/mnt/disk2/users/nstong/repo/Scripts/samflag.pl'

Comment: what is the response of your svn add command and how exactly do you add the file?

Comment: Did you modify the folder structure (ie. copied samflag.pl from some other directory)?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that error when you're trying to add a file in the repository and not in a working directory.

- Did you do a checkout of the working directory ***outside*** of the repository itself?
- Were you able to run the `svn add` command successfully?
- What does the `svn status` command show you?

In fact, are you using the command line or some GUI client to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

In between the initial checkout and trying to add the file I had changed my subversion host settings so that I didn't have to provide the full path to the repository when tunneling.  Just deleting the folder and checking out a new copy of everything allowed me to add the file with no problem.

Comment: As for the questions 
1. I think your asking if checked out the files to a place other than where I created the repository.  If so yes, it was another machine (Although doing that sounds very messy)